# Javascript Nested Loop Issues?

Tags: javascript, loops, cryptography, frequency

I'm attempting to create a small bit of javascript to count the numbers of each letter in a piece of text, for personal use. I had a previous version that had an individual loop for each letter, and it worked, but was rather long, and tedious to create. So I tried to make a shorter one, and I cannot figure out why it doesn't work. Thanks!

```
var text = prompt("Enter Text","");
// Remove Spaces

var text = text.toUpperCase();
// Get the Text Length

var textL = text.length;
// Create the Hashtable

var hashtable = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
// Define the Latin Alphabet

var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
// Nested loop to find frequencies and input them into the hashtable

for (d=0; d<=25; d++) {
    for (i=0; i<=textL; i++){
        if (text.charAt(i) === alphabet.charAt(d)){
            hashtable[d] = hashtable[d] + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are converting your string to uppercase, then comparing it to a lowercase alphabet.

Comment: Please, replace the `= new Array(0, 0,...` by `= []` and simply put `hashtable[d]=0;` in your loop.

Comment: I'll be sure to replace the new Array(0,0... with that, but may I ask why?

And I had no idea I was so stupid as to do compare those two. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to support ECMAScript 5, it's possible to use the new `map` or `reduce` to have a much smaller bit of code.

Given a string you can `split` it, turning it into an array.  You'll want to remove any whitespace beforehand `.replace(/\s/g, '')`, and then `reduce` will iterate over each letter and return a result. The results can be held in an object, with each property name being the letter.

```
var str = "SampleText".toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,'');
var counts = str.split('').reduce(function(acc, x) {
   acc[x] = (acc[x] || 0) + 1;
   return acc;
}, {});
```

Output:

```
{ a: 1,
  e: 2,
  l: 1,
  m: 1,
  p: 1,
  s: 1,
  t: 2,
  x: 1 }
```